# Can we add a screenshot of the "accepted answer" check mark to the help pages?

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

I usually like to link this help page: [Some-one answers](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) to new users that comment ["*Thanks, it worked!!*" on an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/331372/52726).

> <sub>The reason I link them to [Some-one answers](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) instead of [Accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) is because the former one actually has an explanation of how to accept an answer. I actually think that that part should be moved to be under the latter link, and that the latter link should have a title of "*How do I "accept" an answer*". I would definitely link users to *that*. But I digress.</sub>

Can we add a screenshot of the "accepted answer" check-box to that help page? Why?

- I strongly believe that screenshots are an easy way to convey information to the reader. New users might not find the accepted answer check-box even if the text tries to explain where it is, so a screenshot would do.
- The "[To accept an answer:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)" subtitle in that help page links to a StackOverflow question. I think it's great because it further explains the "accepted answer" concept, and it also includes a screenshot, but its a screenshot of the StackOverflow accepted-answer box.

Here's a sample of what I was thinking:

[image]

It probably looks hideous, but that's how I imagine it. The two screenshots I used are [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1g4A.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB1Uo.png).